# How to put link around table data in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to put a link around data in a table. So if the user clicks on the link it will bring them to the edit page for that item. Every time I put the code in the data will disappear from the table. Here is the code for my page I'm working on:

I'm trying to put clickable data at the start of the table code

```
<?php include '../view/header.php'; ?>


<div id="main">

    <h1>Product List</h1>



   <div id="content">
        <!-- display a table of products -->
        <h2><?php echo $name; ?></h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th class="right">Version</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>

            <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <a href="?action=view_product&amp;product_id=<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>"</a></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
                <td class="right"><?php echo $product['version']; ?></td>
                <td><form action="." method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action"
                           value="delete_product" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="productCode"
                           value="<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                </form></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
        <p><a href="?action=show_add_form">Add Product</a></p>
        </br>

    </div>

</div>
<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is no connection to a database here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any closing `</a>` tag and nothing between the opening `<a>` tag and where the closing tag should be.  Here is the problem:

```
<td> <a href="?action=view_product&amp;product_id=<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>"></td>
```

This should be something like:

```
<td><a href="?action=view_product&amp;product_id=<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>"><?php echo $product['productCode']; ?></a></td>
```

Comment: I had </a> before. Sorry i fixed my post. Also I don't want to add text, I want the data to be the text they click on. Like the productCode is what they click onn

Comment: @user2288600 Then echo out the product code again inside the `<a>`. I have updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

May not be the issue, but I don't see a closing  anywhere for the:

```
<a href="?action=view_product&amp;product_id=<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the closing tag for your anchor.  It should be:
 `<td> <a href="?action=view_product&amp;product_id=<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>"><?php echo $product['productCode']; ?></a></td>`

Comment: Sorry I updated my post. I had that in there. It still appears with nothing there.